# How to add Layout on top of another Layout?

Tags: java, android, xml, layout, viewgroup

My English is poor. So I threw off the video. I think any programmer looking at this will understand the reason. Thank you in advance

I want to learn how to use ReleaseativeLayout correctly, because ConstainLayout is very buggy. Even using it in Android Studio Canary.

So I'm using ReleativeLayout and LineartLayout now. These are the most effective ViewGroup. I thought. But it turned out all wrong

[image]

---

XML Code

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    android:background="@drawable/login_faggot">

    <TextView
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_above="@+id/plsLogin"
        android:text="Welcome."
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="@color/grayBg"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/plsLogin"
        android:layout_above="@+id/editLogin"
        android:text="Please Login."
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editLogin"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editLogin"
        android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editPass"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editPass"
        android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <EditText
        android:paddingStart="20dp"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_mail_white_24dp"
        android:drawablePadding="15dp"
        android:hint="@string/user_name"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/buttonLogin"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/buttonLogin"
        android:layout_above="@+id/editPass"
        android:id="@+id/editLogin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <EditText
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_lock_white_24dp"
        android:paddingStart="20dp"
        android:drawablePadding="15dp"
        android:hint="@string/password"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/buttonLogin"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/buttonLogin"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:id="@+id/editPass"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_above="@+id/buttonLogin"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/buttonLogin"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/buttonLogin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <CheckBox
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.CompoundButton.RadioButton"
            android:id="@+id/radioButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Remember Me"
            android:paddingStart="15dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"/>

        <TextView
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:text="Forgot Password"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/buttonLogin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_round_corner"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorOrangeUsSite"
        android:text="@string/login"
        android:textColor="@color/white"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:alpha="0.8"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/layoutProgressBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ProgressBar
            android:theme="@style/ProgressBar"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: If you change to ConstraintLayout, then the bug disappears and everything starts working properly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add one more **Relative Layout** below of your parent layout and set **Gravity** to it

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
android:background="@drawable/login_faggot">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_above="@+id/plsLogin"
    android:text="Welcome."
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textColor="@color/grayBg"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/plsLogin"
    android:layout_above="@+id/editLogin"
    android:text="Please Login."
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<TextView
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editLogin"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editLogin"
    android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<TextView
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editPass"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editPass"
    android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<EditText
    android:paddingStart="20dp"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_mail_white_24dp"
    android:drawablePadding="15dp"
    android:hint="@string/user_name"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/buttonLogin"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/buttonLogin"
    android:layout_above="@+id/editPass"
    android:id="@+id/editLogin"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<EditText
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_lock_white_24dp"
    android:paddingStart="20dp"
    android:drawablePadding="15dp"
    android:hint="@string/password"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/buttonLogin"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/buttonLogin"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:id="@+id/editPass"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_above="@+id/buttonLogin"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/buttonLogin"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/buttonLogin"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <CheckBox
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.CompoundButton.RadioButton"
        android:id="@+id/radioButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Remember Me"
        android:paddingStart="15dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"/>

    <TextView
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:text="Forgot Password"/>
</LinearLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
    android:id="@+id/buttonLogin"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_round_corner"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorOrangeUsSite"
    android:text="@string/login"
    android:textColor="@color/white"/>

</RelativeLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:alpha="0.8"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:id="@+id/layoutProgressBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ProgressBar
        android:theme="@style/ProgressBar"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Only parent layout height and width would match parent instead of a child.
2. you've have entered **FrameLayout height="match_parent"**
3. you've to implement like this.

   ```
    <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    android:background="@drawable/login_faggot">

   <TextView
   android:gravity="center_horizontal"
   android:layout_above="@+id/plsLogin"
   android:text="Welcome."
   android:textSize="18sp"
   android:textColor="@color/white"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
   <TextView
   android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
   android:textSize="16sp"
   android:textColor="@color/grayBg"
   android:gravity="center_horizontal"
   android:id="@+id/plsLogin"
   android:layout_above="@+id/editLogin"
   android:text="Please Login."
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

   <TextView
   android:background="@color/white"
   android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editLogin"
   android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editLogin"
   android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
   android:layout_width="1dp"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
   <TextView
   android:background="@color/white"
   android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editPass"
   android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editPass"
   android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
   android:layout_width="1dp"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <EditText
   android:paddingStart="20dp"
   android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_mail_white_24dp"
   android:drawablePadding="15dp"
   android:hint="@string/user_name"
   android:layout_alignStart="@+id/buttonLogin"
   android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/buttonLogin"
   android:layout_above="@+id/editPass"
   android:id="@+id/editLogin"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
   <EditText
   android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_lock_white_24dp"
   android:paddingStart="20dp"
   android:drawablePadding="15dp"
   android:hint="@string/password"
   android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/buttonLogin"
   android:layout_alignStart="@+id/buttonLogin"
   android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout"
   android:id="@+id/editPass"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

   <LinearLayout
   android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
   android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
   android:layout_above="@+id/buttonLogin"
   android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/buttonLogin"
   android:layout_alignStart="@+id/buttonLogin"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">
   <CheckBox
       style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.CompoundButton.RadioButton"
       android:id="@+id/radioButton"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Remember Me"
       android:paddingStart="15dp"
       android:textColor="@color/white"/>

   <TextView
       android:visibility="invisible"
       android:id="@+id/textView"
       android:textColor="@color/white"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:gravity="end"
       android:text="Forgot Password"/>
     </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
   android:id="@+id/buttonLogin"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
   android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
   android:background="@drawable/button_round_corner"
   app:backgroundTint="@color/colorOrangeUsSite"
   android:text="@string/login"
   android:textColor="@color/white"/>

   <FrameLayout
   android:background="@color/black"
   android:alpha="0.8"
   android:visibility="gone"
   android:id="@+id/layoutProgressBar"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">
   <ProgressBar
       android:theme="@style/ProgressBar"
       android:layout_gravity="center"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </FrameLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
   ```